# Twitter logout using oauth in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master for Twitter+Oauth in my iPhone app.I am creating a music application where user can login and  log out of twitter. This paticular Twitter+Oauth implementation doesn't use sessions, so I'm not sure how this works.

Does anyone have experience with this and if so how would I go about logging out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960957/210774) has answers that will work for you. I'll post summaries here for convenience.

*From [Ryan McGeary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout/1961377#1961377)*:

> The session with Twitter is defined by
>   a cookie owned by Twitter -- something
>   you do not have control over. You
>   cannot log them out of Twitter on
>   their behalf.
>
> If you want someone to be able to use
>   your "switch twitter account"
>   functionality, you'll need to pass
>   them off to the OAuth handshake again,
>   but use the `/oauth/authorize` path
>   instead of the `/oauth/authenticate`
>   path. This will allow the user to
>   switch their user credentials at
>   Twitter during the handshake instead
>   of just re-authenticating using their
>   existing Twitter session.

*From [abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout/1972194#1972194)*:

> You can use `oauth/authenticate` and add
>   `force_login=true` as specified in
>   http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/oauth/authenticate*.
>   This will prompt the user with a login
>   form.

**updated reference to most recent documentation*

If any of answers above work for you, be sure to follow the link and upvote the originals.