# How to post tweet in twitter with the use of oauth in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a  music application in iphone . i want to integrate twitter in my application with the use of Oauth such that when a user log in twitter his username and password details are validated and then the post tweet page is opened where the user  can post his tweets .So, can anybody help me to how to post  tweets in twitter with the help of Oauth authentication.
Please anybody help me regarding this problem.

Comment: How far have you got? Where are you stuck? Which twitter / oauth library are you using?

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500724/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) and [Twitter + OAuth](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) library

Answer (score 0):

Try this with OAuth+MGTwitterEngine :

```
[_engine sendUpdate:[NSString stringwithFormat:@"The date & time is: %@",[NSDate date]]];
```

To post Tweet to one's a/c once you make successful login with Oath.