# Facebook and Twitter in a kiosk environment... auto logouts?

Tags: facebook, twitter, graph, facebook-like

I was wondering if there were any approaches recommended to auto logging out a user from Facebook and Twitter after they click a 'like' or 'tweet this'. I'm running a site in kiosk mode and would like to log them out after performing the previous actions.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

At least with facebook, you can use [FB.logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout) from their JS SDK or if using Connect, `FB.Connect.logout(function() { ... });`

With Twitter, it might not be as straightforward - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout/1961377#1961377).