# Using Twitter api logout on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

User login my application with oauth, after logout my application but twitter can't do, problem is user twitter account is active.

**when that logout my application at the same time logout twitter**

twitter api not support this action?

Comment: hi llyax, i am developing Twitter on iPhone, can you help me what are the method and how to implement the functions, log out the Twitter app in iPhone, help me llyax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter just closing the session at api ,not close the session on Twitter :)

Answer (score 5):

No, the twitter API will not log your users out of twitter.

account/end_session only ends the current API Session. I'm working on an site that requires users to be able to log out and then log back in again with another twitter account. To do that, you have to store multiple access tokens per user and establish one as the current access token. More info in the link below.

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/02e44b27d7ba3661?pli=1

As far as signing out of twitter, it's up to the user to sign into twitter and sign out themselves, which is not ideal if working on a shared computer.

Comment: I'm not a web developer, but if there is a way to have the access token be saved in a temporary way (or deleted when the page closes) you could add **another key/value pair to the access token response body**. Based on this added value, you can handle the persistence of the access token accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to call [account/end_session](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/account/end_session) to end the session of the authenticated user on twitter.

Comment: No reaction , no error all system work :)  message 
 {
  "error": "Logged out.",
  "request": "/1/account/end_session.json"
}

Comment: Then you're settled...make sure you accept this answer if you're satisified :)

Answer (score 1):

Old thread agreed, I just integrated Twitter login in my android app using Fabric. I found the following method

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter.logOut
```

I guess they have implemented it now! I couldn't find any documentation, honestly I've not put too much time into it. But I think logout means what I think it means :)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not have api for logout. You can use the session closing api to end the user session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oauth/authenticate or oauth/authorize and add "force_login=true" parameter. This will prompt the user with a login form.

[view this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout)