# tweetsharp logout

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

Does anyone know how to log a user out of Twitter using Tweetsharp?

I am using `svc.EndSession();` where svc is a `TwitterService` object.

However the user (me) stays logged in. A quick refresh of Twitter.com shows that I am still logged-in even after hitting the logout button (and running `svc.EndSession();`) on my asp.net app.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I've not seen any third-party apps logging someone out of Twitter - only the apps themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `Tweetsharp`, but it seems, that Twitter is holding control over logged in users in a cookie they own. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960957/431657) posted to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960957/431657) states some workaround using the `/oauth/authorize` instead of `/oauth/authenticate` path. Don't know for sure, if that helps you as you are using `Tweetsharp`.

Comment: Hi, I've passed this on to my colleague who belives this may well be the answer - thanks!