# How to log out from twitter

Tags: android, oauth, twitter

I have successfully created an app to login user and post the tweet  using OAuth support
but I cannot figure a way to logout user or force login (using twitter
login). Any help is highly appreciated.

thnks in advance

Comment: Check this link to logout from twitter https://stackoverflow.com/a/49900512/4445489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960957/210774) has answers that will work for you. I'll post summaries here for convenience.

*From [Ryan McGeary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout/1961377#1961377)*:

> The session with Twitter is defined by
>   a cookie owned by Twitter -- something
>   you do not have control over. You
>   cannot log them out of Twitter on
>   their behalf.
>
> If you want someone to be able to use
>   your "switch twitter account"
>   functionality, you'll need to pass
>   them off to the OAuth handshake again,
>   but use the `/oauth/authorize` path
>   instead of the `/oauth/authenticate`
>   path. This will allow the user to
>   switch their user credentials at
>   Twitter during the handshake instead
>   of just re-authenticating using their
>   existing Twitter session.

*From [abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout/1972194#1972194)*:

> You can use `oauth/authenticate` and add
>   `force_login=true` as specified in
>   http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/oauth/authenticate*.
>   This will prompt the user with a login
>   form.

**updated reference to most recent documentation*

If any of answers above work for you, be sure to follow the link and upvote the originals.

Answer (score 0):

What i do for logout is i wont save the security token from `OAuth` . Otherwise it lasts forever, I don't recall seeing a `logout api`.Wat i do is, will leave the token n get the new one at the time of login. There maybe some api for `logout` but im not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the twitter using OAuth support then the user is automatically logged in after first run.
What can be done is to uninstall the whole application as the tokens are saved after first run of the application , so all information remains with the application.