# How to logout from twitter using Fabric Sdk for android

Tags: android, logout, twitter-fabric

I used

```
Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
```

This does not work,next time when i logIn using twitter, it opens the dialog with browser,takes previous login and just asks "Allow app to fetch your data?", but doesn't ask for username and password.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: tried deleting Application cache directory and also deleted browser data using `Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());` , still the same issue

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this situation.

Accidentally, I found a method in Twitter SDK Kit for Android

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
Twitter.logOut();
```

This was very simple, it took me about half an hour to find it.

> For version 3.0 and above

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession()
```

Comment: know how to do this for IOS objective c?

Comment: I literally cannot find any reference to this anywhere. I wonder if the method is asynchronous, or what it actually does. Fabric is poorly documented :(

Comment: The CookieSyncManager is now deprecated. CookieManager.flush is a possible alternative.

Comment: 'android.webkit.CookieSyncManager' is deprecated. @moyheen can you please show sample snippet for how to use CookieManager.flush?

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra if you still need help with that, you may check my answer below.

Comment: the Twitter.logOut() method is no longer available , the ide says 'can not resolve method logOut()' any alternatives?

Comment: @AhmedRajab I have same problem. Did you deal with it ?

Comment: @user7856586 when i log in or out twitter i user a shared preference which holds a boolean value called "twitter" to identify whether i am logged in or out and change the UI according  to that.......
after i log out I clear cookies as described in the answers to stop remembring my account

Comment: @AhmedRajab thnx

Comment: can u please upvote my comment if u find it useful @user7856586

Answer (score 13):

Now that CookieSyncManager is deprecated, I do it this way:

```
public void logoutTwitter() {
        TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        if (twitterSession != null) {
            ClearCookies(getApplicationContext());
            Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
            Twitter.logOut();
        }
}

public static void ClearCookies(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        } else {
            CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
            cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
            CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
            cookieSyncMngr.sync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**LAST WORKING solution:**

```
public static void logoutTwitter() {
    TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
    if (twitterSession != null) {
        clearTwitterCookies(mAppContext);
        Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
        Twitter.logOut();
    }
}

public static void clearTwitterCookies(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();

    } else {
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work for me. I always get the last user logged. I'm using the last version.

Answer (score 2):

The above methods are extinct.

```
// twitter log out
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use:

```
Digits.logout();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
```

This one is the `logout` method when you are login with **Twitter Auth**

Answer (score 0):

To logout current user simply call

```
mTwitter.shutdown();
```