# How to logout Twitter - Twitter4J

Tags: android, twitter4j

I want to log out Twitter. I tried to clear reference and request with a new request URI but my account still login. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout) but it doesn't describe how to login in detail. How to logout Twitter and login with different account? Could you give me some code for logout or relogin?

The function get requet URI

```
public static String getRequestURI() {
    try {
        final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY, Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Constant.CALLBACK_URI);
        return requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
    } catch (final TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

The function clear reference

```
public static boolean logout(final Context context) {
    getPrefs(context);
    CustomSharedPreferences.setPreferences(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
    CustomSharedPreferences.setPreferences(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please see this answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18102116/1237656

Answer (score 0):

```
mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);
mTwitter.shutdown();
```

That works, source http://wenchaokong.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-twitter-integration-twitter4j.html